# From Jordan's Curve Theorem to Jordan-Schoenfliess theorem

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to learn and understand proofs of classical theorems and successfully mastered a proof of JCT.  (It was the well-known proof that uses Tietze Extension and Brouwer's fixed point theorem).  I'd now like to learn a proof of the Jordan-Schoenfliess theorem.  Is there an approach that builds on the Jordan Curve Theorem to prove the Jordan-Schoenfliess theorem so that I don't have to start from scratch?

Thank you,

Paul Epstein

Comment: Yes, of course, the result is usually understood as a corollary. Complex analysis texts may have an outline. See Berenstein-Gay **Complex variables. An introduction**, which has a reasonable outline with additional references, and then discusses recent versions (due to Bell and Krantz) where the boundary is smooth.